# How to redirect to home page after logout in nuxt?

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

after login in site i want when i click to specific button , user log out from site to home page.

here is my `template` code:

```
<template>
  <nav id="header" class="navbar navbar-expand header-setting">
    <div class="main-content">
          <div class="notification" @click="LogOut()"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
```

and here is my `script` code:

```
export default {
  name: 'HeadeAfterLogin',
  methods: {
    LogOut() {
      localStorage.removeItem('token')
    }
  }
}
```

any one can help me to complete LogOut function ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Inside your component you have access to `this.$router`

So you can easily do:

```
export default {
  name: 'HeadeAfterLogin',
  methods: {
    LogOut() {
      localStorage.removeItem('token')
      this.$router.push('/')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: may wanna use this.$router.replace instead of push

Comment: @PirateApp Why?

Comment: @Čamo if the person hits back button on the browser they ll go back to the page where they were logged in, no?

Answer (score 1):

What I am doing is:

**Component:**

```
### html 
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item" @click.prevent="signOut">LogOut</a>

### script
export default {
    methods: {
      signOut() {
        this.$auth.logout();
      }
    }
}
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
        ...
    },
    redirect: {
        login: '/login',
        logout: '/login', # after logout, user will be redirected here.
        home: '/'
    },
}
```